# Can an action be both determined and free?

Tags: reference-request, free-will, determinism, compatibilism

The classical argument against free will, is that, in a deterministic universe, since everything is determined, so are human actions, and thus no human action is free. But this relies on the hidden premise, "No free action is determined". So, can a human action be both determined and free? And what have philosophers said about this question?

Comment: You could start by writing down both definitions, of a determined action and of a free action. Possibly one can read off already from the definitions if they are either conflicting or consistent with each other. - Anyhow I consider this the first step to find an answer to your question. - I suspect that eventually one finds for both alternatives supporting philosophical arguments: The problem of free will in a deterministic context has not been solved until now.

Comment: It depends on the definitions of "free" and "determined". Free will compatibilists define "free" in a way that makes it compatible with "determined" (free from coercion and obstacles, or according with agent's wishes, for example). Free will libertarians reject such redefinitions as twisting the language and make indeterministic "freedom to do otherwise" part of the definition of "free", see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compatibilism/#FreeAccoClasComp). To them, "no free action is determined" is an explicit premise, not a hidden one.

Comment: See this recent debate between [Dennett and Sapolsky](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=aYzFH8xqhns) who clash largely  over what free will means.

Comment: My personal take is that if one person says you aren't free to try what you want to try because you can't not want what you want, and the other person says you are free to try to do what you want right now because you can not want what you want, the one is denying the blatantly obvious and the other is denying the law of non-contradiction. If those are the lacking-X and having-X positions, then X must be meaningless. Calling X with an otherwise meaningful adjective--noun combination like "free will" is just a labeling mistake.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that lumps me in with compatibilists, but having-X-ists might lump me in with lacking-X-ists, I'm not sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can determinists take decisions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70387/can-determinists-take-decisions)

Answer (score 5):

**The issue is *much* more complex.** Compatibilists usually don't claim that *freedom* and *determination* are merely unrelated questions but rather attempt to demonstrate how a non-vacuous concept of freedom of the will is intelligible in a deterministic world. This usually involves demonstrating how skepticism about freedom is based on an equivocation on the notion of 'free' and 'determined' or other subtle logical mistake.

The most straightforward compatibilist answer to the problem of *free will vs determinism* was given by **David Hume** and in the twentieth century by, among others, **Carnap** and **Quine** (who discussed these questions very briefly). Humean compatibilism relies on a) understanding the concept of freedom as at least distinct from our scientific-cognitive notions (and related to ex. moral responsibility, ability to predict consequences of one's actions), b) understanding the notion of necessity or causal connection as a practical approximation for purposes of predicting future events. This is the answer which assumes that the reasoning that you reference is simply metaphysical confusion.

Another answer, given by **Spinoza**, **Kant**, **Schelling**, **Hegel**, **Daniel Dennett** and **Donald Davidson** holds that freedom is inherently related to rationality and thus to being able to justify one's actions and take responsibility for them (Kant has a word for it, *autonomy*) - being, in some, sense identical with *necessity* (in Schelling's slogan). An important feature of these philosophers' ideas is that the same world can be described in two distinct ways, one purely physical or "materialistic" and another "mentalistic" and "rationalizing". Davidson's **anomalous monism** holds that these descriptions are strictly incommensurable, irreducible to each other, because there are no strict psychological laws. It's a subtle doctrine and Davidson's original argument for it can be found in *Mental Events* (but don't be confused - this is not a position just about *freedom*, but about *the mental* in general). Under one description the world is (semi-)strictly deterministic, under another - approximately rational.
(however: Spinoza, strictly speaking, spoke of *freedom* and not *free will* whose existence he denied)

**Daniel Dennett** and the **Churchlands** hold that freedom of the will has a distinct relation to *self-control* (self-regulation, comprehending the consequences of one's actions, deliberation) and should be understood as a "bare" fact about the human brain, a distinctive feature of its functioning which can be studied by the neurosciences. But, of course, while it functions remarkably reliably, it can fail in certain circumstances.

I believe that the question of free will shows that most philosophical questions cannot be tackled one-by-one. Comprehending the views of i.e. Hegel or Davidson requires understanding their general philosophical orientation.

Answer (score 1):

This question is just another way of phrasing "Is compatibilism true or reasonable?" or "Why do people believe in Compatibilism?" or something along those lines.

Like most things in philosophy, there's no canonical, True with a big T, universally accepted answer. The jury is out. There are arguments for and arguments against. There are strong intuitions that it must be true and contrary strong intuitions that there's no possible way it's true. As such, all answers can only amount to the speakers philosophical opinion (in my opinion). The closest you could hope for in regards to expert consensus is finding out that a small majority of professional philosophers do, in fact, accept compatibilism.

I'll give my opinion here though: if freedom is incompatible with determinism, then that means freedom relies on randomness. To me, decisions based on randomness aren't free - randomness cannot give freedom. A person in a world with randomness is a slave to that randomness just as much as a person in a deterministic world is a slave to determinism. Thus, if there is any sort of freedom, it seems to me that it would have to be compatible with determinism.

Comment: a new question on philosophy.stackexchange ?? +1

Comment: Freedom being incompatible with determinism does *not* mean that it relies on randomness. Freedom of choice is actually the very opposite of randomness. If you roll a die, you get a random result. If you put the die in a position of your choice, there is no randomness involved.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question would depend on what you meant by both "free" and "deterministic".

If "free" means I am not aware of being coerced by anyone or anything, and that I have time to "make up my own mind" about what I am going to do, then that does not necessarily contradict the idea that someone else, who knows more about me than I am aware of myself, could have predicted my decision; and that is a form of determinism.

Related to that is the fact that we may be biologically determined to do certain things (breathing, for example). If someone prevents me breathing by covering my mouth and nose, and I then escape from their clutches, I might feel I am free to breather again: but the fact that I am biologically determined to breather sometimes means my freedom is only contingent on doing so "sufficiently often" for my physiological systems to allow.

If the above does not answer your question (perhaps I missed the point) then please say more about exactly what you meant about "free" and about "deterministic"

Answer (score 0):

[Is tossing of a coin deterministic experimemt?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570241/1068723)

This related question was posted at the Math SE and is worthwhile reading.

There are two kinds of randomness: epistemic and nonepistemic. The former means that the random element is one’s knowledge, and the latter means that the randomness is intrinsic to the process itself. Radioactive decay is an example of nonepistemic randomness.

A coin flip obeys the laws of classical mechanics and quantum effects are negligible. Once the coin is flipped, classical mechanics drives the process to its outcome. This portion is a deterministic process and if one filmed and measured the trajectory of the coin, one could set up a system to repeat the outcome.

A person is free to choose heads or tails without disrupting the physics of the coin flip. This choice is based on epistemic randomness.

So, arguably  the guessing of a coin flip is both deterministic and free.

Comment: There is nothing deterministic about coin flip. In determinism there is only one possible outcome. Flipping a coin is an act of free will making the coin fly with random direction, lateral and rotational momentum.

Answer (score -1):

All actions are determined *by something.*

- A free (voluntary) action is determined *by the agent* herself.
- A non-free (involuntary) action is determined *by prior events*.

In a deterministic system everything is determined by prior events. There are no agents capable of self-determining their actions.

Comment: Our physical theories don't describe what a mathematician would call "a deterministic system".

Comment: @abcga That is true. The physical reality is not a deterministic system.

Answer (score -1):

In the debate video Sapolsky Asks - Where did that intent come from? Sapolsky Answers - From a (deterministic) natural process. However, we do not know for certain if every natural process, and therefore every product of that process, is deterministic. If a process is not deterministic then it is probabilistic. Then recognition of free will is not compatible with the belief or conviction that the will is emergent from an underlying deterministic or probabilistic natural process. In actual contemplation the psychogenic process is The Great Mystery and the product of this process have psychogenic attributes. The recognition of free will, the vagueness of such recognition, and the inherent uncertainty, are co-arising products of the mysterious psychogenic process.

In the context of psychogenesis the question can be reduced to a cognitive map model where concepts of action, determined, and free are theoretically independent of each other, but then determined and free are juxtaposed as mutually exclusive attributes of action. Then the subject maps a relation {action, free} or {action, determined}. The fact is that subjects called philosophers can endlessly debate and dispute the veracity of these cognitive mappings but so far have no means to resolve the disputes. I map the uncertainty to the cognitive process and not to attributes of so-called external reality.